# Determining entropy of vaporization

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

In the following van der Waals formula [image: Entropy calculations of a van der Waals fluid], would shifting the ideal-gas entropy on the left-hand side create an entropy of vaporization equation? In other words, does the real-gas entropy minus the ideal-gas entropy equal the entropy of vaporization?

P.S. I am trying to calculate b in a van der Waals equation by using the entropy of vaporization

Comment: What is the exact statement of your homework problem?

Comment: @ChetMiller At 25 °C and 3169.93 Pa (vapor pressure), water has a liquid molar volume of 1.807×10-5 m3 mol-1, a vapor molar volume of 0.7809 m3 mol–1, and an entropy of vaporization of 147.57 J mol–1 K–1.

a) Use the entropy of vaporization to calculate b in the van der Waals equation.

b) Use the liquid molar volume to calculate a.

c) Use a and b to calculate Tc and pc. Compare with the actual values (Appendix D).

Answer (score 0):

If you accept the idea that, for a VDW fluid, the pressure at a given constant temperature is a continuous function of the specific volume from the saturated liquid to the saturated vapor, then the entropy change between these two states is given by $$\Delta S_{vap}=R\ln{\left(\frac{V_V-b}{V_L-b}\right)}$$

$$\frac{\Delta S}{R}=17.75$$So, $$\frac{V_V-b}{V_L-b}=51.1\times 10^7$$If is obvious that b is going to be negligible compared to $V_V$.  So, $$V_L-b=\frac{V_V}{51.1\times 10^7}=1.53\times 10^{-8}$$So, $$b=1.807\times 10^{-5}-1.53\times 10^{-8}=1.855\times 10^{-5}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115265/discussion-on-answer-by-chet-miller-determining-entropy-of-vaporization).